# 'default_value' plugin does not run if 'get' returns null or empty value

Tags: 8, migrations

I’ve got a D7 to D8 migration where I’m trying to migrate a field with a null value in D7 to a default value in D8. Process pipeline is similar to this:

```
  field_privacy:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_office_privacy
    -
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: 'open’
```

It seems if the field value is null, the default_value plugin never runs.

When D7 has a non-null value, then the field migrates perfectly via the `get` plugin. The D8 API documentation gives this pipeline as an example of exactly what I'm trying to do, yet I cannot get it to work. When I should get a value for all 164 items selected by the migration source, I instead only get 132, which precisely matches the number of fields in D7 that have non-null values.

How can I set a default value when `get` doesn't find a value?

Answer (score 2):

The catch here is that you should not use the `get` process plugin explicitly. The behaviour you want is already implicitly used the `default_value` plugin. This is because [get is the default process plugin and can be shorthanded](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/migrate-process-overview#single_plugin). In your case this should work:

```
 field_privacy:
   plugin: default_value
   source: field_office_privacy
   default_value: 'open’
```

Also see documentation for [get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!migrate!src!Plugin!migrate!process!Get.php/class/Get/8.8.x) and [default_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21DefaultValue.php/class/DefaultValue/8.8.x)